# Using Flow and Powerapps to create library item usage approval

Tags: custom-list, custom-form, picture-library, flow, powerapp

I am using SharePoint Online.

I have a library (Image Library) and a custom list (Request use of image).

I would like users to be able to view an item in the image library, and then click a button on the view item form which says 'Request'. This needs to create a new item in the request use of image list, pre-populate a couple of fields, and prompt the user to complete a third.

The new item form of list needs to have a 'Submit' button which then launches an approval process.

I have tried various combinations of Powerapps and flows, but with zero luck. Is it just too complicated for a non-professional to set up?

Is there any other way to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Just wondering if you could share what you have tried so far and what won't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a screen 1 in Power apps to display all items in the library. I would give a selected item request button to this screen.

Then write a formula to navigate to screen2, everytime a request button is clicked.
Once in screen 2, I will write a formula to update that request in "request use of image list". So the request gets captured into this list.
Create a column named submit with yes/no type, write a approval flow to trigger whenever the column has yes type value.

Let me know if any doubts